# Jquery function not recognized if jquery file is not included in the included jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Hi have a Main Jsp file where I have included jquery.infinite-scroll.js. This main.jsp has one included jsp say incl.jsp. Now the function for infinite scrolling is defined in the main jsp like

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

     $(function(){
            var $container = $('#container');

            $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
                $container.isotope({
                    itemSelector: '.box',
                    gutterWidth: 10
                });
            });

            $container.infinitescroll({
                        navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation
                        nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
                        itemSelector : '.box',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
                        debug: true,
                        loading_image: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif',
                        loading: {
                            finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
                            img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
                        }
                    },
                    // trigger Masonry as a callback
                    function( newElements ) {
                        console.log('I m here');
                        // hide new items while they are loading
                        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
                        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
                        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                            // show elems now they're ready
                            $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                            $container.isotope( 'appended', $newElems, true );
                        });
                    }
            );
        });
    });
```

Here container div is in the main.jsp

```
<div id="container" class="transitions-enabled infinite-scroll clearfix centered">
    <%@ include file="/incl.jsp" %>
</div>
```

Now if I do not include the infinite-scroll.js in this included jsp, browser is throwing error that $container.infinitescroll is not a function.

Why do I have to include the js file in the included jsp?

Comment: Sounds very simple. The object which you want to use is defined in `jquery.infinite-scroll.js` and not in `incl.jsp`

Comment: Sorry for being unclear here. What I mean to say is that if I include "infinite-scroll.js" in the main.jsp it should work but its not working till I include infinite-scroll.js in the incl.jsp too.

Comment: @jindal there is no need include the js in `incl.jsp`, having them in `main.jsp` will be enough. Make sure the js is included properly in `main.jsp` by debugging the rendered html.

Comment: @vjy I have verified the html and it does contain the include tags for the js file but still its behaving weird.

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive... should 'S' be caps in infiniteScroll ?